# Display Location Details with ACF (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, maps, advanced-custom-fields

According to [ACF's documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/), I'm showing the details of the Google Maps field address with this snippet:

```
$location = get_field('location');
if( $location ) {

    // Loop over segments and construct HTML.
    $address = '';
    foreach( array('street_number', 'street_name', 'city', 'state', 'post_code', 'country') as $i => $k ) {
        if( isset( $location[ $k ] ) ) {
            $address .= sprintf( '<span class="segment-%s">%s</span>, ', $k, $location[ $k ] );
        }
    }

    // Trim trailing comma.
    $address = trim( $address, ', ' );

    // Display HTML.
    echo '<p>' . $address . '.</p>';
}
```

Is there a way to display more details?

Example:

```
Street number: 44
Street name: Bowery
Neighborhood: Chinatown
Borough: Manhattan
City: New York
Postal code: 10013
County: New York
State: New York
Country: United States
Formated address: 44 Bowery, New York, NY 10013, USA
```

Comment: What do you mean with "more details?" You talk about the "keys"? or the missing fields? if it's the latter then the real question is: how the ACF field is configured? which type is it? provide a screenshot of it so we can help you

Comment: I'm trying to display the name of all the administrative level (corresponding to the address entered) on the front-end. According to ACF's documentation: "The Google Map field provides an interactive map interface for selecting a location. This field type uses the Google Maps JS API to provide autocomplete searching, reverse geocoding lookup and an interactive marker. New: The Google Map field saves more location data in version 5.8.6!" The code provided above is inserted directly into a front-end PHP code block and returns a formatted address.For my project, it is missing: county, borough...

Comment: Currently, the snippet provided by ACF only returns: 123, Foo Bar Street, Melbourne, Victoria, 3000, Australia.

Comment: Backend screenshot: https://cutt.ly/Nha74Ds / Front-end screenshot: https://cutt.ly/lha7MB4